# Регулярное выражение в рамках одной строки

Tags: c#

Как в с# задать регулярное выражение, которое ищет тот файл в котором в рамках одной строки (!): в начале строки стоит слово start, а в конце той же строки - finish (при этом между словами может быть что угодно).
Примерно так: ^start.*finish$ (но не так)

Comment: а почему не так?

Comment: `ищет тот фай` - что это значит ? вам сначала List файлов нужно получить , а потом вызвать только те в которых строки совпадают условию ? , и что это за файлы (txt, html, exe, dll)  - вопрос тянет на минус. От типа файла зависит способ поиска совпадений, и почему `REGEX` а не Linq

Answer (score 1):

```
var linesOfFile = File.ReadAllLines("путь до файла"); // .ToList(), если необходимо.
```

После этого, в цикле, вы сможете проверить все, что вам необходимо, в рамках одной строки. А регулярка вот: `^start(\s|\S)+finish$` В будущем можете воспользоваться https://regex101.com/

Comment: `\s|\S` - можно просто `.` - _точка_ - означает любой символ.

Comment: `ReadAllLines` возвращает массив, так что `ToList` точно не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

```csharp
private bool Test(string path)
{
      var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
      foreach (var line in lines)
          if (line.StartsWith("start") && line.EndsWith("finish"))
                return true;
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Лучше всё-таки использовать `ReadLines`, чтобы не держать в памяти всё сразу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov здесь не соглашусь, размер предполагаемого файла максимум 20 мегабайт (не думаю что данным способом терабайты анализируют) а миллион обращений к жёсткому диску ненужные операции.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хотя если нахождение нужной строки в индексе меньше 30% от количества строк файла - то да рациональней `ReadLines`.